# Decompiled and Replaced SWF File Not Working

Tags: javascript, actionscript-3, flash

I have an web application which has SWF file and uses AS 3. My aim is to decompile SWF file and replace the original one on web page with this decompiled and then recompiled one.

The decompiled file is on local machine (which is recompiled to SWF). But after replacing the file calls to the AS 3 code (ExternalInterface.callback) are not working , basically the SWF file itself not working even though decompiled and recompiled file has NO code change or Its also not working when I simply replace SWF file with local one.

```
<object classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" id="player" width="1" height="1" codebase="http://fpdownload.macromedia.com/get/flashplayer/current/swflash.cab" data="http://<Path to SWF fiel>" type="application/x-shockwave-flash">
                <param name="movie" value="http://<path to swf>">
                <param name="quality" value="high">
                <param name="bgcolor" value="#<>">
                <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="always">
                <embed src="http://<path to swf>" quality="high" bgcolor="#869ca7" id="embedplayer" width="1" height="1" name="player" align="middle" play="true" loop="false" allowscriptaccess="always" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" flashvars="vars" pluginspage="http://www.adobe.com/go/getflashplayer" style="display: block !important;">

</object>
```

I am replacing the src using JS.

Comment: Why you dont use your original source to compile your swf?

Comment: If the ExternalInterface calls not working, you properly havn't defined it?

Comment: No I am using same file without changes , just from local version (downloaded from site). Which works fine when SWF file is from server (src value) but dosent work when its attached from local.